# Peculiar calculation of the Klein-Gordon Propagator

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fourier-transform, propagator, klein-gordon-equation, analyticity

I am reading Peskin & Schroeder's QFT textbook (page 29~30).

Here, to calculate Klein-Gordon Propagator, author computes following integral.

$$\left< 0 | [\phi(x), \phi(y)]|0\right> = \int \dfrac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3}\dfrac{1}{2E_{\mathbf{p}}}\left( e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}-e^{ip\cdot(x-y)} \right) = \int \dfrac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \left\{ \left[ \dfrac{1}{2E_{\mathbf{p}}} e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}\right]_{p^0 = E_{\mathbf{p}}} +\left[ \dfrac{1}{-2E_{\mathbf{p}}} e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}\right]_{p^0 = -E_{\mathbf{p}}} \right\}.\tag{2.54}$$

Here, $p$ and $x$ are 4-vector and $x^0 > y^0$. I understand that this is algebraic sum of the propagator for particle and anti-particle respectively. And then, I've encountered the PECULIAR computation:

$$ = \int \dfrac{d^3 p}{(2\pi)^3} \int\dfrac{dp^0}{2\pi i} \dfrac{-1}{p^2-m^2}e^{-ip\cdot(x-y)}.\tag{2.54}$$

Where does this integral come from?

Comment: More on [P&S eq. (2.54)](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=is%3aq%20peskin%202.54).

Comment: This is just the (reversed) residue theorem applied to inverse Fourier Transform of $\frac{1}{2E_\textbf{p}}$.